# How do I combine multiple signals for synchronous playback in NAudio without using wav files?

Tags: naudio

I want to combine multiple signals for playback without having to write to wav files first. In other words, a basic additive synthesizer.

I noticed in the "Play Sine Wave" demo (https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/Docs/PlaySineWave.md) I could probably call the Play method on multiple signal generators in a nested using statement. However, I am not sure how many of these I can call without introducing latency between signals. This looks like a sketchy approach even with just two signals.

So do I have any other options, and how would I implement them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `MixingSampleProvider` and add as many signal generators as you like as input (best to reduce their output volumes so you don't end up with clipping).

Then just play from the `MixingSampleProvider` directly.